# cypress. how to cy.url().should('eq', 'url_example/')?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

How to verify correct link redirection after pressing link button?

Cypress failed test because of
assert expected https://initial page url/ to equal page what I need to check url correct redirection.

Answer (score 1):

If there are other elements in the URL you're not worried about then you could try to use 'contains' rather than 'eq':

```
cy.url().should('contain', 'url_example')
```

Or something similar to that. cy.url() just returns a text string so should be easy to handle within a test.

Comment: thanks for comment, but the problem that the new page opens after link clicking. getting same error message with 'contain'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like the following code:

```
cy.visit('www.example.com/login')
cy.url().should('eq', 'www.example.com/login')
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Don't just dump code and expect everyone to understand it.